# Clause structure

Tags: clauses

I came across a structure, which I have tried to dissect it to know its function and grammatical name.

However, at a glance I said, the highlighted group of words was a **clause( Noun clause)** which functions as **Subject**. Below is the sentence........

1. The team **the school presented** was a strong one.

Yet, I am not sure. Could someone help me to clear the discombobulation ?

Comment: Note that if you say "The team was a strong one" you have the same meaning (if the team is identified by context).  Removing modifying clauses often makes it easier to parse a sentence.  (Just be sure to remove the *entire* modifying clause.)

Comment: Also note that "the school presented" functions as an adjective (modifying "team"), not a noun.  So it can't be the subject.

Answer (score 2):

The subject of your sentence is *the team the school presented,* the verb is *was*, and the subject complement is *a strong one*.

*The school presented* is a restrictive relative clause that gives more information about *the team*. In this case the word that ordinarily introduces a relative clause has been omitted:

> The team (that) the school presented was a strong one.

[The UNC Writing Center website suggests](https://writingcenter.unc.edu/relative-clauses/) that the omission can happen here because "that" serves as an object pronoun in the relative clause. This is quite common in speech:

> Object pronouns can be deleted.
>
> - I like the bike that my father gave me.
> - I like the bike my father gave me.

Comment: Essentially correct. However, since the restrictive relative clause is within the subject, the subject of the sentence is [the team the school presented], not just [the team].

Answer (score 0):

Clause = Subject + Predicate

Subject = The team the school presented

Predicate = verb + object

Verb = presented

**presented = show or offer something for others to scrutinize and consider. Submit for observation.**

Object = was a strong one

The meaning of the sentence really seems to lie in the verb in this example. "Presented" means to show something expecting feedback, so that alone paints the picture of whatever team is being referred to is putting themselves out there for observation. That implies pride, competition, hurt egos, sadness, joy, the possibility of winning, losing, sweat, tears, sex, hope, goals, dreams,and recognition.

All of these different constructs implied by a single word...